# How can be done by the method of mathematical induction?

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics, induction, recreational-mathematics, fractions

We are given that $P(x+1)-P(x)=2x+1$
We also know that $P(0)=1$
We want to prove that $P(2004)=(2004)^2 +1$
Can someone explain how can be solved with mathematical induction?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Show $P(n)=n^2+1$ by induction.

Comment: The Induction Step: Suppose that for a particular non-negative integer $k$, we have $P(k)=k^2+1$. Then from $P(k+1)-P(k)=2k+1$, we find that $P(k+1)=P(k)+2k+1=k^2+1+2k+1=(k+1)^2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $P(y)=y^2+1$ satisfies the conditions [Proof below]

So, if $P(x)=x^2+1, P(x+1)=P(x)+2x+1=x^2+2x+1+1=(x+1)^2+1$

---

[
**Proof**:

As $P(x+1)-P(x)=2x+1$

$P(x)$ can be at most Quadratic Polynomial

Let $P(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ as $P(0)=1, A\cdot0^2+B\cdot0+C+C\implies C=1$

So, $P(x)=Ax^2+Bx+1, P(x+1)=A(x+1)^2+B(x+1)+1$

So, $2x+1=P(x+1)-P(x)=A(2x+1)+B=2Ax+A+B$

Equating the coefficients of $x,2=2A\implies A=1$

Equating the constants $A+B=1\implies B=0$

]

Comment: @Nick, my pleasure

Comment: While this is a great solution, the problem as stated asks to prove $P(y)=y^2+1$ by induction.

Comment: The question asked for a solution by induction. Also, how can you be sure that P(x) is (at most) a quadratic polynomial? Or even a polynomial at all?

Comment: @Relsiark, Th solution uses induction $P(x)->P(x+1).$ How can the difference be $2x+1$ if $P(x)$ is not polynomial. If $P(x)$ is of degree $n,P(x+1)-P(x)$ will be of degree $n-1$

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction that $P(k) = k^2 + 1$:

**Basis:** $k = 0$: $P(0) = 1 = 0^2 + 1$, check.

**Induction:** Suppose it is valid for $k$:

$$
\begin{align*}
P(k + 1) &= P(k) + 2 k + 1 \\
         &= (k^2 + 1) + 2 k + 1 \\
         &= (k^2 + 2 k + 1) + 1 \\
         &= (k + 1)^2 + 1
\end{align*}
$$
This checks.

By induction, this is then valid for all $k \ge 0$.